# Aframe - Videos and videospheres with sound doesn't work on IOS

Tags: aframe

I've tried all the solutions given in this post "https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/316#issuecomment-170182397" and other similar posts but none of them work.

What I want is to play a video with sound when a user clicks on the video.

I have this glitch below created but it only works if I add the "muted" attribute to the video tag.

[https://glitch.com/~grey-acoustic-swordfish](https://glitch.com/%7Egrey-acoustic-swordfish)

Do you have any ideas to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Safari doesn't allow autoplay for videos with audio](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/safari_tools_and_features/delivering_video_content_for_safari):

> A  element can use the play() method to automatically play without user gestures only when it contains no audio tracks or has its muted property set to true

You have to start playing the video on user gesture if you want audio. I added `video.play()` to your a 2D button handler below:

```
<button onclick="playVideo();">Play Video</button>

function playVideo() {
  var vid = document.querySelector('#video');
  vid.muted = false;
  vid.play();
}
```

[Modified example](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/sassy-storm-wholesaler?path=index.html%3A42%3A14)

Comment: Thanks for you answer Diego!
I don't to autoplay the video with sound, what I want is to play the video with sound when a user look at the object but it isn't possible without having a touch or a mouse click on the screen. I fixed this adding this line above the camera entity "<a-entity raycaster="objects: .clickable" cursor="rayOrigin: mouse;"></a-entity>"